# Compile and build Eclipse plugin with Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have been making eclipse plugins for a little while now and I am wanting to automate the build process. I have lots of plugins/packages installed that compile and build locally.

Here is a picture of my eclipse installation details:

[image]

You can see that I have a lot of stuff installed that my plugins depend on. My first task is just to get everything to compile in Jenkins. I have tried to make an ivy.xml and place all the dependencies in there. I have found it to be a complete mess. Has anyone done this before? If so, what has your approach been?

Answer (score 0):

We used [Tycho maven plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Tycho) for building our eclipse plugin. [Here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp01/) is simple example.
Project structure:

```
28.08.2015  15:37               890 pom.xml
28.08.2015  15:37    <DIR>          tycho.demo.itp01
28.08.2015  15:37    <DIR>          tycho.demo.itp01.tests
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tycho.demo.itp01</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>tycho.demo.itp01</module>
    <module>tycho.demo.itp01.tests</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
    <tycho-version>0.23.1</tycho-version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>helios</id>
     <layout>p2</layout>
     <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios</url>
   </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Structure of tycho.demo.itp01:

```
28.08.2015  15:37               374 .classpath
28.08.2015  15:37               677 .project
28.08.2015  15:37    <DIR>          .settings
28.08.2015  15:37               109 build.properties
28.08.2015  15:37    <DIR>          icons
28.08.2015  15:37    <DIR>          META-INF
28.08.2015  15:37             1 655 plugin.xml
28.08.2015  15:37               335 pom.xml
28.08.2015  15:37    <DIR>          src
```

tycho.demo.itp01/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>tycho.demo.itp01</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>tycho.demo.itp01</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you ever installed Eclipse on a Jenkins slave?